# Computer is running slowly, browser hangs all the time, checked memory and seems to be fine. Any suggestions?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My computer (Compaq Presario CQ61) feels like its just about to give up the ghost, but its only a year old. I'm running Windows 7 Home Edition on it.

I've run a memtest86+ test on it and it hasn't detected any errors. There's no blue screens, or sudden system crashes, the browser just hangs whenever a page with more than medium size content is delivered.

My desktop apps don't seem to be running any slower than normal as far as I can tell.

I run AVG antivirus and it hasn't detected anything after daily scans.

Important point to note, the battery has gone because it only lasts about 10 minutes without being plugged in. I don't see how that would specifically affect browser performance, though.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: which browser ??

Comment: Firefox is what I use. But since you said that, I'll just test IE and Chrome to see if they're hanging as well.

Comment: If your browser is slow but your other apps are okay, then it would be your connection to the Internet and/or the connection between your PC and modem.  What kind of connection do you have to your ISP (ADSL or cable or ?)?  What kind of connection between the modem and PC (wired or wireless Ethernet)?

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty sure it isn't because it has happened in a few different loactions all of which I'm confident in the internet connection. When Firefox hangs, I get a "Firefox Not Responding" Message at the top of the browser and the screen goes paler and I can't click on anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try a wired Ethernet connection, instead of wireless.

Comment: Ah. Good idea. I'll give that a go when I get a cable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, just like any program with plugins, is vulnerable to mistakes by plugin authors.  It's possible that a plugin has slowly corrupted the installation.  On occassions, I've found it beneficial to recreate my Windows user profile and forcing the programs to basically recreate all their registry settings and such.